# Javascript/Jquery Link change form dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This may come off as confusing or simple i have no idea.

I have a picture, when you click on an element in the picture, i need the dropdown in the next div along to change.

```
<a href="eastern#browse" class="areaselect" rel="region_7" id="eastern" title="Eastern England image">Eastern England</a>
<a href="western#browse" class="areaselect" rel="region_8" id="western" title="Western England image">Western England</a>
```

That is an example of the links, this is an example of the dropdown.

```
<select name='areapick' id='apick'>
    <option value='placea'>Placea</option>    
    <option value='placeb'>Placeb</option>    
    <option value='placec'>Placec</option>
    <option value='placed'>Placed</option>    
    <option value='placee'>Placee</option>
</select>
```

Before anything is clicked, I dont want the menu to appear, but when they click say Eastern England i want Place A & B to appear in the dropdown, if they select Western England I want Place C, D & E to appear.

I have tried using an onclick which i could do easily to get the select menu to appear, but i can't get it to filter and remove elements etc or show/hide the div. I am already using the latest Jquery min library on the page. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the new html (with different classes for eastern and western) :

```
<select name='areapick' id='apick'>
        <option value='placea' class="eastern">Placea</option>    
        <option value='placeb' class="eastern">Placeb</option>    
        <option value='placec' class="western">Placec</option>
        <option value='placed' class="western">Placed</option>    
        <option value='placee' class="western">Placee</option>
    </select>
```

here is the javascript I would use:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.areaselect').on('click', function(event){
            var id = $(this).attr('id')
            $('#apick option').not('.'+id).css('display','none');
            $('.'+id).css('display','inline').first().attr('selected','selected');
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

notice the "link" between `<a> #id` and `<option> .class`
(script not tested)

Comment: Ran this thru on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dJbNA/) Its outputting an error saying to use post request. Which i am assuming related to onclick not being valid. 

Is there an easy way (with ur script) to hide the form prior to any clicks?

Comment: I've edited my code... when is the error triggered ? and what does it says ?

Comment: There is no error message any more but all items appear by default. My query is this. When you click western, it still shows Place A as the selected item, is it possible to change this or would that make things alot more complicated (if not then not a big issue). But hiding it all together prior to a click is v.important. 

In regarding changing the selected item (top), would having seperate select menus make this easier, so 2 dropdowns (1 eastern, 1 western) and the click changes which is visible and sets a text field to the name of the one being used for proper form handling.

Comment: now the first selected item is ok. to have an empty list by default add a css `#apick option{display:none;}`

Comment: Perfect thankyou, made a v.minor tweak to hide form by default. Very much appreciated thankyou! http://jsfiddle.net/dJbNA/1/ (for others who need the final solution) Marking as answered

Comment: no prob, to stack options replace 'inline' with 'block' in the javascript

Answer (score 0):

With the same structure you can try using the ***gt*** and ***lt*** selectors of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.areaselect').on('click', function(){
         $('#apick').css('display','none');
         $('#apick option').css('display','inline');
         var title = $(this).attr('id');
         if(title.indexOf('eastern') != -1){
              $('#apick option:gt(1)').css('display','none');//Zero based index
         }
         else{
              $('#apick option:lt(2)').css('display','none');//Zero based index
         }
         $('#apick').css('display','inline-block');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd give both the `a` tag and the corresponding `option` tags the same class. Then, `onclick` I'd display the relevant options:

```
<a href="eastern#browse" rel="region_7" class="eastern" title="Eastern England image">Eastern England</a>
<a href="western#browse" rel="region_8" class="western" title="Western England image">Western England</a>


<select name='areapick' id='apick'>
        <option value='placea' class="eastern">Placea</option>    
        <option value='placeb' class="eastern">Placeb</option>    
        <option value='placec' class="western">Placec</option>
        <option value='placed' class="western">Placed</option>    
        <option value='placee' class="western">Placee</option>
    </select>
```

JS:

```
$("a").click(function(){
this_class= $(this).attr("class");
$("#apick").find("option").hide(); // reset
$("#apick").find("." + this_class).show(); // show desired options
});
```